# How to check if data is coming from a secure session created by a specific certificate or not (openssl)?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have multiple certificates on server through which multiple secure sessions can be created and wants to limit the data execution based the certificates.

For example, let's say I have two certificates cert_A and cert_B.
I have 3 commands which are cmd_1, cmd_2 and cmd_3.

I want that only cmd_1 executes for all the connections created through cert_A and others for cert_B.

Both the certificates are placed in non-volatile memory.

The server is implemented in C++ using openssl library.

Is there any thing like I can read the data from the locally placed certificates and match it with some information from the established secure connection like subject name through the API

```
X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, name_length)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, you have the subject name right here. You might also poke around and get some other field from the ceritificate, like emailAddress. Now you have an identifier for  your certificate, and all the information you need to decide what this certificate is allowed to do, so what exactly is your question, it's unclear?

Comment: I am a little new to openssl so I just wanted to confirm what information (should be full proof) from the certificates (incoming connection and the locally placed one) can be used to match so that the commands can be restricted based on the certificates.

Comment: This is something that you need to ask your certificate authority. Your certificate authority can designate whatever field in the certificate as an authoritative identifier for the certificate's owner. commonname, emailaddress, or anything else. This is something that you need to decide, noone else except your certiificate authority can give an authoritative answer for this.